# How to reset Facebook like count to 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have a campaign that we run yearly. We built new pages using last year's page as a template. The pages are at the same URL's as last year but with different content and different metadata.

We thought the client would be happy that they had great social numbers but they actually want the numbers to start from 0. I've found plenty of information about clearing the cache with Facebook and we've done that already in multiple fashion, and plenty of posts asking why their like count is at zero, but nothing about how we can reset to 0.

Any ideas on how we can achieve this?

Comment: What kind of pages are you trying to effect? facebook fan pages? pages hosted on a site thats not facebook?

Comment: These are Facebook like counts on a regular web page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the URLs of the content and the new URLs will have 0 likes